# How to run specific list of specs using Jenkins, Grails and Geb/Spock

Tags: grails, jenkins, spock, geb

I have 2 questions:

- What is the right command to execute a specific list of tests in Jenkins?

We have a Jenkins instance up and running and have set up a grails job to run our functional tests. Jenkins runs fine when specifying no spec or specifying 1 spec. However, when passing it 2 specs, only the first spec runs.
In the command line, I run my tests as such: grails test-app functional: TestASpec TestBSpec2 and it works.
In Jenkins, I tried:

`"test-app -functional -Dgeb.build.baseUrl=http://localhost:32000/MyApp TestASpec Test2Spec"` but it doesn't work.

TestASpec would run but not Test2Spec.

`"test-app -functional -Dgeb.build.baseUrl=http://localhost:32000/MyApp TestASpec"` would run fine.

- I don't understand the meaning of `baseUrl` and also, do arguments passed to the command line overwrites the ones defined in GebConfig?

Thanks in advance

Olivier

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I just had to replace `-Dgeb.build.baseUrl` by `-Dgeb.baseUr`l and it all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
-Dgeb.build.baseUrl=http://localhost:32000/MyApp
```

is JVM argument that set geb framework url to test against.

Same way you can set the enviroment property to tell geb what driver to use

```
-Dgeb.env=firefox
```

if Jenkins runs only grails command it should be set as

so I guess your command should be

```
 test-app -functional: TestASpec TestBSpec2 --baseUrl=http://localhost:32000/MyApp
```